# Problems Connecting to SICK LMS 291 Via USB Port

Tags: ros, sicklms, pioneer, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
When trying to connect the SICK LMS 291 camera to the computer using the navigation stack launch file:

it hangs at:
*** Attempting to initialize the Sick LMS...
Attempting to open device @ /dev/ttyUSB0

for around ten seconds then responds with:

ERROR: I/O exception - SickLMS::_setupConnection: - Unable to open serial port
ERROR: I/O exception - SickLMS::_setupConnection: - Unable to open serial port
[ERROR] [1304122217.282315542]: Initialize failed! are you using the correct device path?
[sicklms-1] process has died [pid 11826, exit code 2].
log files: /home/jason/.ros/log/2c3bbec6-72be-11e0-b96b-0016ea7abacc/sicklms-1*.log

or using the sicktoolbox_wrapper tutorial- http://www.ros.org/wiki/sicktoolbox_wrapper/Tutorials/UsingTheSicklms - it just hangs at:

```
*** Attempting to initialize the Sick LMS...
Attempting to open device @ /dev/ttyUSB0
```

indefinitely. I was wondering if anyone had an idea of what I was doing wrong? I am connected via a serial to usb connector and am running ubuntu 10.10. Also when I open the C: drive it doesn't show that the SICK is connected, and I'm not sure if it is supposed to or not before I correctly run the commands I'm trying to run above. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Jason

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9851/problems-connecting-to-sick-lms-291-via-usb-port/) by [Jason](https://answers.ros.org/users/359/jason/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-04-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jason](https://answers.ros.org/users/359/jason/) on 2011-05-02**:
Are you talking about editing the code? If so then what I did was copy the sicklmswrapper over to my robot_2dnav package and edit that code as mentioned but I'm not sure that it called to that package or the unwritable one in the ros stack. Any ideas of if I should do that differently?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-04-30**:
Have you tried the solution here? http://answers.ros.org/question/257/unable-to-get-data-from-sick-laser-on-pioneer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0